# Problems deploying spring boot project on wildfly server

Tags: java, spring-boot

During deployment of a spring boot project on a wildfly server the following errors are thrown. So how can these errors be resolved?

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/text/markup/TemplateConfiguration
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.text.markup.TemplateConfiguration from [Module "deployment.AlMadinaLibraryServices.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
        ... 54 more



Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration due to org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:54)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:88)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:71)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isConditionMatch(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:515)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:498)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:431)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.getMatchOutcome(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException from [Module "deployment.AlMadinaLibraryServices.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
        ... 38 more


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: VFS resource ["/D:/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/content/AlMadinaLibraryServices.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration.class"]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration due to org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:224)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: VFS resource ["/D:/wildfly-9.0.2.Final/bin/content/AlMadinaLibraryServices.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration.class"]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration due to org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:454)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:290)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:325)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:242)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:184)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not evaluate condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseConfiguration due to org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException not found. Make sure your own configuration does not rely on that class. This can also happen if you are @ComponentScanning a springframework package (e.g. if you put a @ComponentScan in the default package by mistake)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:54)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:88)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:71)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isConditionMatch(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:515)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.isCandidateComponent(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:498)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:431)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedDatabaseCondition.getMatchOutcome(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:128)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException from [Module "deployment.AlMadinaLibraryServices.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
        ... 38 more
```

Comment: It's too hard to read your question description. As far as i can figure out it seems to be an issue of unavailable library in your classpath.

Comment: please format your code and try to post a specific question

Answer (score 0):

Your WAR file "AlMadinaLibraryServices.war" is missing several dependencies. You have to add at least groovy and spring framework / Spring-Boot dependencies.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/text/markup/TemplateConfiguration
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.text.markup.TemplateConfiguration 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException
```

But probably more stuff is missing. Maybe before you do this you familiarize yourself with the overall topic of spring boot, WAR files and so on...